# Календарь: как определить номер недели?

Tags: html, javascript

Как в HTML определить, какой на данный момент номер недели? Ну например, если сегодняшняя дата - первое января понедельник, то номер недели = 1. А если восьмое января вторник, то номер недели = 2. (Это просто пример). Возможно ли это через Javascript? Я могу обойтись в принципе и без календаря, если что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://weeknumber.net/how-to/javascript

Даже целый сайт есть, посвященный этому

Answer (score 0):

Текущий день недели.

```
var weekdays = ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб']
console.log(weekdays[(new Date()).getDay()]);
```

Подробнее: http://javascript.ru/Date/getDay

Comment: Нет. Мне нужен не текущий день недели. Мне нужен номер недели.